# how to configure number of app-icons panels?

Tags: home-screen, 7.1-nougat, app-icons

I just got a new Moto Z2 Play with Android 7.1.1

There's only **two** app-icons panels ( the panels that appear when you swipe the home screen left or right to view additional icons ).

On my Moto Z Play ( also Android 7.1.1 ) I have **seven** panels.

I've spent some time searching through settings and googling and can't determine how to configure the # of panels.

Comment: Umm... A new panel should automatically appear when you drag and hold an app and want to place it somewhere.

Comment: Sounds like someone needs a custom launcher, like Nova Launcher (as an example).

Answer (score 1):

Unless Motorola have significantly changed the way the homescreen works from stock Android, it only creates as many panels as it needs to show the icons. To add a new panel, press-hold-and-drag an icon to where a new panel would be, then drop it on that new panel. Now you should have one more panel than you did before.